# Pgfplots ybar with fading color

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to generate a ybar plot with fading from and back to transparent for each bar. I want for each bar a full transparent color at the beginning and full transparent at the end again. Now it seems, the fading is set once and applied to all bars.

How can I set the fading individueally for each bar? Any ideas?

Thank you!

[image]

```
\documentclass [tikz] {standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ >=stealth]

    \begin{axis}[xbar stacked,
    axis lines*=left,
    width=15cm, height=6cm,
    xtick = {1,10},
    xmin=1, xmax=10,
    xmode=log,
    xmajorgrids=true, xminorgrids=true, minor tick num=1,
    ymajorgrids=false, yminorgrids=false,
    bar width=15pt,
    symbolic y coords={One,Two,Three,Four},
    ]

    \addplot[draw = none] coordinates % Invisible 1. bar
        {(1,One) (2,Two) (2,Three) (2,Four)};

    \addplot[draw = none, fill=blue!30!black, path fading=west] coordinates
        {(1,One) (2,Two) (2,Three) (2,Four)};

    \addplot[draw = none, fill=blue!30!black] coordinates
        {(1,One) (2,Two) (2,Three) (2,Four)};

    \addplot[draw = none, fill=blue!30!black, path fading=east] coordinates
        {(1,One) (2,Two) (2,Three) (2,Four)};

    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```